# Multiple rich:subtables not showing side by side

Tags: jakarta-ee, datatable, richfaces

I am trying to print the multiple lists from the main list using rich:subtables in a rich:datatable

Following code shows the main data table and with it have two subtables:

```
    <rich:dataTable  styleClass="table table-bordered"  value="#{PowerOfAttorneyController.gpaAndExecutorList}" var ="gpaAndExecutor">
              <f:facet name="header">
                    <rich:columnGroup>
                        <rich:column colspan="3">
                            <h:outputText value="Executed by" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column colspan="3">
                            <h:outputText value="POA" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column breakBefore="true">
                            <h:outputText value="Name" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column>
                            <h:outputText value="Father/Husband Name" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column>
                            <h:outputText value="CNIC" />
                        </rich:column>

                                <rich:column>
                            <h:outputText value="Name" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column>
                            <h:outputText value="Father/Husband Name" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column>
                            <h:outputText value="CNIC" />
                        </rich:column>
                     </rich:columnGroup>
                </f:facet>
                <rich:subTable  var="executor" value="#{gpaAndExecutor.ownerexecutedBylist}">
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{executor.personName}"></h:outputText>

                    </rich:column>
                       <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{executor.fatherHusbandName}"></h:outputText>

                    </rich:column>
                       <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{executor.nicNo}"></h:outputText>

                    </rich:column>
                     </rich:subTable>

                  <rich:subTable 

                    var="poa" value="#{gpaAndExecutor.plotOwnerPoaList}">
                    <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{poa.personName}"></h:outputText>

                    </rich:column>
                       <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{poa.fatherHusbandName}"></h:outputText>

                    </rich:column>
                       <rich:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{poa.nicNo}"></h:outputText>

                    </rich:column>
                     </rich:subTable>

 </rich:dataTable>
```

Both lists start showing in the same first three columns which are refereed to **Executed by** in the header. I want second list to go in the next three columns as it refers to **POA** header.

Comment: So you have six columns and want one subtable to cover the first three and the second the other three? That's not supported, and I'm not sure you can do something like that even with CSS.

Comment: @Makhiel so is there any solution for such problem?

Comment: Do it with a single sub table.

Comment: @EJP the table structure would become messy?

Comment: You have to do it manually. You can create table manually with a4j:repeat for example or you can create a wrapper for `plotOwnerPoaList` and `gpaAndExecutorList` (simple Pair will be enough).